# Why my BMI code shows the wrong categories? For example when I get BMI = 21.7 but it prints the OVERWEIGHT statement

Tags: python

```
Weight = float(input("Enter your weight (kg) : "))
Height = float(input("Enter your height (cm): "))
Height_M = float(Height/100)
BMI = float(Weight/Height_M**2)
BMI_R = round(BMI,1)
if BMI_R < 18.5:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are UNDERWEIGHT.")
elif(18.5 > BMI_R < 24.9):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are NORMAL.")
elif(25 > BMI_R < 29.9):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OVERWEIGHT.")
elif BMI_R > 30:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OBESE.")
```

[REFERENCE][1]

Examples
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQBGJ.png

Comment: You have the compare signs flipped in middle two statements, it should be `# <= BMI_R < #` and not `# > BMI_R < #`.

Comment: thank you so much sir. it works.I just started learning python hence the "silly" mistake  

Answer (score 0):

```
Weight = float(input("Enter your weight (kg) : "))
Height = float(input("Enter your height (cm): "))
Height_M = float(Height/100)
BMI = float(Weight/Height_M**2)
BMI_R = round(BMI,1)
BMI_R = 21.7
if BMI_R < 18.5:
  print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are UNDERWEIGHT.")
elif(18.5 < BMI_R < 24.9):
  print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are NORMAL.")
elif(25 < BMI_R < 29.9):
  print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OVERWEIGHT.")
elif BMI_R > 30:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OBESE.")
```

`18.5 > BMI_R < 24.9` --> `18.5 < BMI_R < 24.9`

`25 < BMI_R < 29.9` --> `25 < BMI_R < 29.9`

You added `>` instead of `<`. Please look closly.

Comment: thank you sir. it works.I just started learning python hence the "silly" mistake 

Answer (score 0):

Your range comparisons for normal and overweight are wrong. The left comparison operator for those two cases needs to be '<'.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are wrong. You can try the following conditions.

```
if BMI_R < 18.5:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are UNDERWEIGHT.")
elif(18.5 < BMI_R < 24.9):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are NORMAL.")
elif(25 < BMI_R< 29.9):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OVERWEIGHT.")
elif BMI_R > 30:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OBESE.")
```

or even you can write these conditions.

```
if BMI_R < 18.5:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are UNDERWEIGHT.")
elif(BMI_R < 24.9):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are NORMAL.")
elif(BMI_R< 29.9):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OVERWEIGHT.")
elif BMI_R > 30:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI_R} and you are OBESE.")
```

The second chunk of code seems smarter to write.

Comment: hello, @Jemx if you feel this is the correct answer then you can mark it as an answer and this will help others as well.